# iOS - Storyboard - localization - After modifying storyboard, how to sync to other language storyboard?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I know how to turn on storyboard's localization. The problem is I don't know how to sync all localizaion storyboards, after main (English) storyboard is modified.

Is there any shortcut to sync them? Do I have to do all those modifies again and again in over **TEN** language storyboards?

My condition is: I have a project with over ten localizations. After I released it on AppStore, we have new user requirements.Then, we start program next version app. After I completed tons of improving and creating on stroyboard, I feel desperate to facing other language storyboards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using iOS version >= 6 (and Xcode >=4.5), you can use a single storyboard for multiple languages, i.e., do base localization + the usual string localization. Doing so, you have only to care about the localized strings in string files.

For a guide, see e.g. [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1467446).

Comment: The key point is, the last script, not original one in his suggested link can update your .strings file. Xcode can invoke the script with proper setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting iOS 6.0, you can use Base.lproj like Matthias mentioned.

If you're targeting a release prior to 6.0, you can use ibtool's localization merging features. They works for NIBs, XIBs and Storyboards. You can invoke them like this:

```
ibtool path-to/development.storyboard --local-
       ize-incremental --previous-file path-to/development-storyboard-localization-was-based-on.storyboard --incremental-file path-to/previous-localized-storyboard.storyboard--write path-to/updated-localized-storyboard.storyboard
```

What that does is open development.storyboard, copies it, and the compares all localizable properties between path-to/development.storyboard and path-to/development-storyboard-localization-was-based-on.storyboard, if those properties are the same, the counterpart value from path-to/previous-localized-storyboard.storyboard is copied forward to path-to/updated-localized-storyboard.storyboard, otherwise the current development value is left in place.